# Automatically delete row after 10 ninutes after creation - Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem in Automatically delete row after 10 ninutes after creation - Databases using php

Comment: you need a cron job.

Comment: Or a [MySQL event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html)

Comment: @Strawberry Ah yes, making fun of people. That will help them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table has a `creation_time` column, the following query will delete the old rows:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE creation_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE);
```

You can run this periodically using the [MySQL Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html).